How did router with VPN expose local IP address?
I have a Reyee RG-E5 router. I have it configured to use OpenVPN and all traffic uses that connection. Everything works as expected and my IP exposed to the world resolves to whichever VPN location I have configured.
This morning I had to restart my router and, for a brief period of time, my local IP was exposed while running a speed test.
Is this a bug with the router itself? A flaw in implementation of the OpenVPN client? Expected behavior and the hardware cannot guarantee traffic will always pass through the VPN client?

Does your particular OpenVPN client have a network kill switch feature? note that this is a feature of the client, not a feature of the protocol, so if you need that feature you will have to ensure that your client supports it and that it is enabled.

@FrankThomas - I'm using ExpressVPN and exporting their configuration to be used by my router. They claim that feature is enabled on all of their clients.

right, but if you import configuration into a client that doesn't have a kill-switch feature, like their client app has, then that configuration will be ignored (or the service will fail to come up). you don't have one of their clients, you have the client your router manufacturer shipped.

if you are really worried about it, i recommend you drop a second router in place outside of your current one, and configure its firewall to deny all traffic except traffic passing through the vpn connection created by your existing router. that way if the inner router ever loses its VPN connection, the outer router will block any exposed traffic. that is the easiest way to be sure.

"This morning I had to restart my router..." It takes a finite time for a VPN to connect to the local server. For a few seconds, the PC was running sans VPN, until it reconnected.
